# sort descendingly based on multiple parameters in Java

Tags: java, sorting, date-sorting

I have input of multiple strings where I parse each one to fetch certain data and then display them accordingly. The point is I need to sort them accodring to some parameters before displaying them.
To clarify:

```
String s1 = "a1 5 2014-12-05";
String s2 = "a2 10 2014-12-06";
String s3 = "a3 5 2014-12-04":
```

After pasring each string, I need to sort them descendingly first according to the second parameter and then according to the date whenever I reach a tie for example.

Output should be:

```
a2, a1, a3
```

Any idea how can this be achieved or if I could change the way to a more efficient one?!

Comment: Split strings and compare according to the rule.

Comment: @mic4ael could you clarify more?!

Comment: Create an `Object` (yes, that's what the first `O` in `OO` stands for) that contains three fields: a `String`, an `int` and a `LocalDate`. Then `implements Comparable<MyObject>` and you can use any number of methods to sort a `Collection` of `MyObject`.

Comment: This is exactly what `Comparator`s were designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the data and use [Collections#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-). Your class can define some natural ordering using `Comparable` and in case if you want to sort descending then just pass [Comparator.reverseOrder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) as second arg to `Collections#sort`  like this

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class DateSorter {

    static class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
        String id;
        int num;
        Date date;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        public Entry(String id, int num, String date) throws ParseException {
            this.id = id;
            this.num = num;
            this.date = sdf.parse(date);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entry o) {
            return date.compareTo(o.date);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + '\'';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String s1 = "a1 5 2014-12-05";
        String s2 = "a2 10 2014-12-06";
        String s3 = "a3 5 2014-12-04";

        String[] split = s1.split(" ");

        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new Entry(split[0], Integer.parseInt(split[1]), split[2]));
        split = s2.split(" ");
        entries.add(new Entry(split[0], Integer.parseInt(split[1]), split[2]));
        split = s3.split(" ");
        entries.add(new Entry(split[0], Integer.parseInt(split[1]), split[2]));

    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    });

        System.out.println(entries);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[a2', a1', a3']
```

Comment: Nearly there: _I need to sort them descendingly first according to the second parameter and then according to the date_. You need to sort by `id` then by `num` and finally by `date`.

Comment: Does OP want to sort the data twice ? I mean do we need to add   Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
    return o2.num.compareTo(o1.num);
   }
  });

Comment: @sol4me I know this may sound stupid but I got this error:
The method reverseOrder() is undefined for the type Comparator

Comment: reverseOrder is defined in JDK 8 Which JDK are you using ?

Comment: Given that you wrote the code for JDK8, why aren't you using `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `Comparator.thenComparing` and all their friends?

Comment: @sol4me I am using JDK 1.7

Comment: @sol4me just another question. If I'm using timestamps instead of date, can timestamps parse the date string as shown in your example? I mean would it be possible to sort according to the timestamp?

Comment: @omarsafwany java.sql.Timestamp extends java.util.Date so there should not be any problem with sorting. In constructor you can create new Timestamp object like new Timestamp(sdf.parse(date).getTime());

Comment: @omarsafwany why would you be using `java.sql.Timestamp`? It's for pulling a `TIMESTAMP` time out of a database - it wraps `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I want to have full time "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" so I thuoght of using TimeStamp

Comment: @omarsafwany I'm not sure you understand what a `Date` or a  `Timestamp` is. Read the documentation rather than make assumptions. And with all future interactions with the Java library pay attention to packages. `Timestamp` is in `java.sql`, you aren't doing anything with SQL so it isn't what you need.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I got the difference now and I changed the timestamp as it's not the on I need. The problem now is that I am getting Unparseable date when I added HH:mm:ss although I followed the exact format.
String s1 = "a1 5 2014-12-03 12:14:40";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
this.date = sdf.parse(date);

Anything wrong noticed here?!

Comment: @omarsafwany you need to update the code , currently you are passing only the date, now you need to pass both date and time string as 3 parameter like this entries.add(new Entry(split[0], Integer.parseInt(split[1]), split[2] + " " + split[3]));

Comment: @omarsafwany this is an entirely different question. Post it as such with all the details and for formatted code. Rather than an illegible comment.

Comment: @BoristheSpider my bad, I apologise.